# How to lazy load an audio component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, lazy-loading

[image]

I have this application of a word bank for students and it can play the audio for the words coded like this:

```
import { IconButton } from "@chakra-ui/button";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { HiSpeakerWave } from "react-icons/hi2";

const useAudio = (url: string) => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(url));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  }, [playing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener("ended", () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener("ended", () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, []);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

interface Prop {
  url: string;
}

const Player = ({ url }: Prop) => {
  const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(url);

  return (
    <IconButton
      size={"sm"}
      colorScheme="teal"
      aria-label="Play Audio"
      borderRadius={"full"}
      icon={<HiSpeakerWave />}
      onClick={toggle}
    />
  );
};

export default Player;
```

I don't want all the audio to be fetched because the user will never play them all in one session. What changes do I need to make to this to make it lazy? For it to only load when a user clicks play. I think of someone way to wrap the component inside of a click and then return a component that loads and plays the actual audio.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this approach where I set the URL for the audio through a state. This doesn't give me errors and plays the audio.

```
const useAudio = (url: string) => {
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio(undefined));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url.length) {
      setAudio(new Audio(url));
    }
  }, [url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url) {
      audio.play();
    }
  }, [audio]);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  }, [playing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener("ended", () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener("ended", () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, []);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

const Player = ({ url }: Prop) => {
  const [_url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(_url);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (_url === url) {
      toggle();
    } else {
      setUrl(url);
    }
  };

  return (
    <IconButton
      size={"sm"}
      colorScheme="teal"
      aria-label="Play Audio"
      borderRadius={"full"}
      icon={<HiSpeakerWave />}
      onClick={handleClick}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same lazy loading (audio player) for one of my clients.
Let me give suggestion in short which will help you (If not do let me know) - **Use Redux and dispatch the action on click of every play button.**

**Note:** action should take an `arg` of `url`.